# SQL query get first punch and lastpunch for every employee

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data in SQL Server:

[image]

What I need is that for every day by employee (employeeId) I get in the follwing data:

[image]

`AccessCode` column means `I = PunchIn` and O = `PunchOut` and we have to filter by `lunchtype = 'N'`

So basically the result should return only one row per day and all the punch ins and punch outs in the middle of the first entrance and last exist shouldn't be considered.

> Any clue?

Comment: Could yo paste the data as text, it will be easy to test.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you've tried anything. If you want someone to do your work for you, you should at least post DDL (a table definition), as well as some insert statements to set up sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation :

```
select employeeid, In, Out,
       dateadd(second, datediff(second, in, out), 0) as Hours
from(select employeeid,
            min(case when AccessCode = 'I' then timestamp end) as In,
            max(case when AccessCode = 'O' then timestamp end) as Out
     from table t
     where lunchtype = 'N'
     group by employeeid, convert(date, times)
    ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
with cte as
(select
  *,
  cast(times as date) as myda
from myTable
)

select
  employeeid,
  mn as punch_in,
  mx as punch_out,
  datediff(minute, mn, mx)/60.0 as hours
from
(select
  employeeid,
  min(times) over (partition by myda) as mn,
  max(times) over (partition by myda) as mx
from cte
) t
group by
  employeeid, mn, mx
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select employeeId,
       min(case when accessCode = 'I' then timestamp end) punchIn,
       max(case when accessCode = 'O' then timestamp end) punchOut
from myTable
where lunchtype = 'N'
group by employeeId
```